# jQuery display if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show/hide an element on mouse click but it has to be the element that is clicked not just the class because multiple classes will exist on the page.

Heres what I've got;

```
<i class="fa fa-bars dropMenu">here</i>

<nav class="drop-down">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Buy Now</a><span>5</span></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

the javascript

```
$(".dropMenu").click(function(){
    if ($(".drop-down",this).is(':visible')) {
        $(".drop-down",this).hide();
    } else if ($(".drop-down",this).is(':hidden')) {
        $(".drop-down",this).show();
    }
});
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/75yek8do/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/75yek8do/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must stick to your current markup and have many dropdowns :

```
$(".dropMenu").on('click', function(){
   $(this).next('.drop-down').toggle();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75yek8do/10/)

Comment: So yours is the best solution it works on fiddle but not on my personal site - http://xronn.co.uk/menu/ any idea? (resize window to view i class icon)

Comment: Your markup is different on your live site, sec let me change it

Comment: Its unable to find the classes because of the bootstrap right?

Comment: It's not just due to bootstrap, it's the way it's being targeted.

Comment: If you can move the toggle icon next to the dropdown so they become siblings it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You've not included jQuery and you're using `<i>` as a context but it is inline element and cannot have any elements inside it. So remove `this`, as the context.

```
$(".dropMenu").click(function() {
    if ($(".drop-down").is(':visible')) {
        $(".drop-down").hide();
    } else if ($(".drop-down").is(':hidden')) {
        $(".drop-down").show();
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/75yek8do/1/)

But you can simply `toggle` it

```
$(".dropMenu").click(function(){
   $('.drop-down').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are http://jsfiddle.net/75yek8do/2/

You can have as many as you like items to click on (.dropMenu). It will search for the next occurrence of the .drop-down element and it will toggle its visibility.

```
$(".dropMenu").on('click', function () {
    $(this).next(".drop-down").toggle();
});
```